# Overriding a condition defined in an association in a find

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a service where users are able to upload cars to the site, and select the manufacturer and model from a list. If the car model does not exist, the user can save a new model under the specific manufacturer.

Now to my problem, all models have to be confirmed by a moderator as being a valid type, having a correct spelling, and not being a duplicate etc. All confirmed models are visible to other users. I do this by specifying a condition in the Car's association as below:

```
$belongsTo = array(    
  'CarModel' => array(
      'className' => 'CarModel',
      'foreignKey' => 'car_model_id',
      'conditions' => array('CarModel.confirmed' => 1),
      'fields' => '',
      'order' => ''
  ));
```

However, I want to override this condition in the edit action so that the user can see his models, even if they are not confirmed yet. Is that possible in the find conditions?

Regards,
Roland.

Answer (score 0):

You can **bind model** before calling *find()* method. Try this in your action.

```
    $this->ModelName->bindModel(
        array('belongsTo' => array(
                'CarModel' => array(
                    'className' => 'CarModel',
                    'conditions' => array('CarModel.confirmed' => 0),  // Define your new condition here
                )
            )
        )
    );
$data = $this->ModelName->find('all'); // Now you will get the data for new condition applied
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: Also if this bind conflicts any other bind that is already defined `unbind()` the one that you don't need.

Comment: Yes. use `$this->ModelName->unbind()` in case it conflict. Call `unbind()` before calling `bind()` method.